# Can the iPad remember the iTunes password when using Meraki MDM?

Tags: ios, ipad, mdm, meraki

I'm currently using Cisco Meraki MDM to manage apps that get pushed out to company-owned iPads. In order for the company to retain ownership of the apps we purchase, apps are installed through the company iTunes account.

The problem is that when the apps installed with that account have updates to install, the user is being prompted for the password of the company iTunes account. I don't want to give the users this password for several reasons - to keep the password from being changed, to keep apps from being purchased on the company account, etc.

Is there a way to set the iPad to remember the password for the iTunes account so the user is not prompted for it when updates are installed? And if not, is there a way to bypass this issue when pushing out apps through MDM?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Google tells me "No, mostly."

https://docs.meraki.com/display/SM/Systems+Manager+FAQ#SystemsManagerFAQ-

> Does the
> user have to enter the Apple ID password for every app installed?
>
> When
> Apps are deployed via MDM, Apple requires an Apple ID and password for
> the app to be installed. Apps downloaded and installed via Apple
> Configurator do not require entering an Apple ID and password,
> however, the iOS device has to be physically connected to the OS X
> device running Apple Configurator.
>
> With iOS 6, the device caches a
> users password for 15 minutes. If you install FREE apps in batches via
> Systems Manager with iOS 6, you will have to enter the password once
> instead of doing it for every single App.
>
> Paid apps redeemed via VPP
> redemption codes still require the user to enter a password for EVERY
> app. Devices running pre-iOS 6 will be required to enter a password
> for every app regards of whether it is free or paid

Some further Google searching says that some MDM applications have an unsupported way of doing what you want, but Meraki doesn't. Blame Apple for this requirement.

Comment: It sounds like the OP may just have to keep up with the updates of the deployed applications, which sucks but I'm with you: *Blame Apple*.

Comment: Corporate IT Department's don't decide to buy Apple devices... Apple's target market are the middle-aged technology-challenged (eg CEOs and Soccer Moms), people who make spending decisions. I doubt iPhones will ever support easy configuration management natively given the products market placement (premium devices that compete on namesake, momentum, and ecosystem rather than features and price). I am amazed that no competitor (Android, BB, etc) has integrated management into their products (especially when the CEO calls and IT and wants their phone/tablet/etc to "just work".

Answer (score 3):

When you enable the VPP programme users will authenticate with their own iTunes account when you push apps to them.

1. First, read [this KB article](https://kb.meraki.com/knowledge_base/deploying-vpp-apps-to-ios-devices-using-apples-managed-distribution-model) for an overview of how to use
   Apple's VPP Managed Distribution model with the Meraki Dashboard.
2. Obtain a Volume Purchase Program account from Apple, for
   [business](http://www.apple.com/business/vpp) or [education](http://www.apple.com/education/ipad/volume-purchase-program/).
3. Download, open in a text editor, and copy your VPP service token,
   found on the VPP purchases page
4. Add an account on the [Organization > Settings page.](https://n35.meraki.com/Wireless/n/Vg_uabJ/manage/organization/edit#apple_vpp_accounts)